# Which community should I ask a question relating to file sharing?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am bit confused with choosing which Stack Exchange site to ask my question on. I fear it may be downvoted if I post in the wrong community.

The question I want to ask is:

---

I am trying to find a file sharing service or website which offers a password protect feature to a file. The thing is I can find a website which offer the feature as below:

1. Upload a file to get a password
2. Give it to a friend who wants to download the file
3. He goes to the webpage and unlocks the file using the password I
   gave, and then downloads the file

This is the the usual procedure, eg for Dropbox.

But what I need is something different, as explained below.

1. Upload a file to get a password
2. Give the password to a friend who wants to download the file
3. He goes to the web page and **first** downloads the file and
   **then** unlocks it using the password

Is this possible? Does any file hosting site offer such a service?

I know that I can use password protected `.rar` files, but it becomes impossible for me to do it that way because I change the password frequently, and I have a lot of files, some quite large files too.
So the processing power and time to do it that way is not efficient.

---

Please suggest a Stack Exchange site where I can post the above question.

Answer (score 4):

It *might* be on-topic at [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com). They have stringent requirements for questions, so be sure to read their [Help Center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [Question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Questions asking for recommendations are otherwise almost completely out of scope for the rest of Stack Exchange. If your thought was to ask at [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com), please don't. It will be closed there.